# What is sigma function in the YOLO object detector?

Tags: neural-networks, image-processing, notation, object-detection, yolo

I have gone through the [YOLO9000 paper](https://pjreddie.com/media/files/papers/YOLO9000.pdf), in that they have mentioned that network predicts 5 coordinates of the bounding box, and from that we find the exact centre coordinates and the width and height. I'm confused with those equations.
\begin{align}
b_x &= \sigma(t_x) + c_x  \\[3pt]
b_y &= \sigma(t_y) + c_y  \\[3pt]
b_w &= p_we^{t_w}  \\[3pt]
b_h &= p_he^{t_h}  \\[3pt]
Pr({\rm object})\times IOU(b, {\rm object}) &= \sigma(t_o)
\end{align}

In these equations, what does $\sigma$ stand for? Why they are using exponential for width and height?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is the logistic sigmoid function:
$$
\sigma(x) = \frac 1 {1+e^{-x}}
$$
It is bounded between 0 and 1, which is a desired property in their case (image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function)):

[image: Logistic sigmoid]

Regarding the exponential, see [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/345267/163572).

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the notation using the symbol $\sigma$, the caption to one image names this function the "sigmoid" function. From the paper,

> Figure 3: Bounding boxes with dimension priors and location
>   prediction. We predict the width and height of the box as offsets
>   from cluster centroids. We predict the center coordinates of the
>   box relative to the location of filter application using a sigmoid
>   function.

The "sigmoid" function is one of many names for a certain function. This name is especially common in the neural networks literature; for some elaboration, see [Does the function $e^x/(1+e^x)$ have a standard name?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/371402/does-the-function-ex-1ex-have-a-standard-name/371403#371403)